# Authentication to pages on GitHub Enterprise

Tags: c#, github-pages

Our company is using GitHub **Enterprise** within which I have a repo. I have posted some static web content to a pages site in the repo. Having already logged in within the browser I can view those pages without issue, but I want a desktop app to be able to consume that static content (C# example):

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

    private const string Scheme = "https";
    private const string BaseDomain = @"mycompany.domain";
    private const string BasePath = @"pages/myorg/myrepo";
    private const string InfoPath = "info.json";

    var uriString = $"{Scheme}://{BaseDomain}/{BasePath}/";
    var httpClient = new HttpClient{BaseAddress = new Uri(uriString)};

    var infoString = httpClient.GetStringAsync(InfoPath).Result;

    var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Info>(infoString);
```

The `GetStringAsync` call returns a "friendly" error page instead of the static content because the site needs the client to log in or otherwise authenticate. Do I have any option besides username/password (I don't want to hard-code a username/password or force the user to enter a credential into the app). Is there any alternative which could be "baked in" to the app such as app ID and secret or a certificate, and if so, how do I set it up in the repo and how do I inject the authenticator into my app's request?

**Use Case:**
The application is for company-internal use (the repo contains the app source); I am looking at github pages as a method for the app to detect if a newer version is available. The idea is that when a new version is published, the github page would be updated. When the app is launched, it would get and parse that page, and if it indicates the existence of a newer version, notify the user.

Comment: So this is a private repo?

Comment: @stuartd GitHub Enterprise is installed on our internal corporate network; doesn't matter if the repo is configured as public or private, pages still requires a login, even within the network.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. Can you use a repo token?

Comment: @stuartd I was reading about tokens, just not clear how to use in my C#. I assume I'd have to include an Authorization header on a SendAsync call, not clear what the header content would need to be.